# lex - how to eliminate double quotes from a string literal

Tags: c, lex

I want to eliminate double quotes which are at the beginning and end of a string.

I take a string literal from my input file using a Lex rule as follows:

```
\".*\"   {yyno++; yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return STRINGLITERAL;}
```

But when I use a string somewhere in Yacc program, I want to use only the string part.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Your pattern for a string literal is both too greedy and not greedy enough.  It is too greedy because it will parse: `"abc" + "def"` as a single string literal (which is not the way string literals are usually defined).  It is not greedy enough because it doesn't handle double quotes embedded in the string.  There are two main ways of handling those: (1) doubling up the double quote (`"abc""def"`, which is the string literal `abc"def` when the double quotes are removed), or (2) using an escape character, usually backslash `'\\'` to handle it (`"abc\"def"`). Choose which you convention want.

Comment: Isn't that a Lex rule, rather than a Yacc rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to take the relevant part, eg:

```
 // you allocate a string which is the length of the token - 2 " + 1 for '\0'
 yylval.string = calloc(strlen(yytext)-1, sizeof(char));
 // you copy the string
 strncpy(yylval.string, &yytext[1], strlen(yytext-2));
 // you set the NULL terminating at the end
 yylval.string[yytext-1] = '\0';
```

So that if `yytext == "\"foobar\""` first you allocate a string of length `8 - 2  + 1 = 7` bytes (which is correct since it will be `foobar\0`, then you copy 8 - 2 characters starting from `'f'`, finally you set the `NULL` terminating character.

Actually with calloc memory is already set to 0 so you don't need to place the `NULL` terminating character but with `malloc` you would.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definiton.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

```
\".*\" {
    yylval.string = (char*)calloc(strlen(yytext)-1, sizeof(char));
    strncpy(yylval.string, &yytext[1], strlen(yytext)-2);
    return STRINGLITERAL;
}
```

Jan explained it well, I'm just clarifying the lex and fixing a few typos for the next poor soul.